# Handles clause requires a WithEvent variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types

Tags: asp.net, database, error-handling, backend

I keep on having this error in one of my project files. I use the same code in another file in the project and it has no error. Just this file in the project has it. Can somebody tell me why and how to solve it?
Here is the code for that part:

for the aspx file :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Email Ticket" Font-Bold="true"   BackColor="#66ccff"/>
```

Meanwhile for the aspx.vb file:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Public Class viewTickets
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub


    Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Response.Redirect("Email.aspx")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check if inside the designer file you have the correct declaration of your button? IE: _Protected WithEvents Button2 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.LinkButton_ (or whatever type Button2 is)

Comment: after adding the declaration, it works. Thank you so much